# Fill Angular form from developer console

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

In Angular 8 I was able to do this:

```
const el = document.querySelector("#first-name);
if (!el) { console.warn(item.selector, 'not found'); return; }
const probe = ng.probe(el);
const ref = probe.providerTokens.find(p => p.name === 'NgControl');
const directive = probe.injector.get(ref);
directive.control.setValue("Johnnie");
```

This would find an `input` with a `formControlName` and Reactive Forms based code behind it, set its value, including triggering of any change detection in Angular.

In Angular 9 with Ivy this no longer works, as `ng.probe` has been removed in favor of other tooling, most notably `ng.getComponent`. However, that method seems mainly useful for getting actual Angular components, and I'm unsure how I can use that to edit form values and trigger change detection.

What would be the Angular 9 & Ivy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me, you just change the input value in plain JS and then trigger the change event. You can use the same event for multiple inputs.

```
const changeEvent = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
changeEvent.initEvent("change", false, true);

const el = document.querySelector("#first-name");
el.value = 3;
el.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```